# Displaying all shapes in size legend geom_point ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

There are 3 shapes used in my plot and only the solid circle is used in the `size legend` (shown on the chart). I am trying to find a way to include all of the shapes in that legend, is there a way to do it?

**dataframe and code for the plot:**

```
data <- structure(list(date = structure(c(1431388800, 1444780800, 1456876800, 
    1469145600, 1469664000, 1425081600, 1445299200, 1488758400, 1524960000, 
    1454544000, 1540512000, 1429228800, 1481587200, 1526688000, 1445904000, 
    1498348800, 1464825600, 1451174400, 1450310400, 1539216000, 1528934400, 
    1525996800, 1465084800, 1531180800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
    ), tzone = "UTC"), cnt1 = c(76, 140, 99, 10, 123, 124, 160, 58, 
    47, 43, 86, 112, 26, 123, 111, 49, 65, 93, 174, 49, 5, 16, 84, 
    4), cnt2 = c(111, 200, 550, 73, 123, 184, 166, 131, 189, 136, 
    250, 195, 26, 154, 125, 100, 168, 151, 255, 49, 200, 144, 177, 
    4), per = c(68.4684684684685, 70, 18, 13.6986301369863, 100, 
    67.3913043478261, 96.3855421686747, 44.2748091603053, 24.8677248677249, 
    31.6176470588235, 34.4, 57.4358974358974, 100, 79.8701298701299, 
    88.8, 49, 38.6904761904762, 61.5894039735099, 68.2352941176471, 
    100, 2.5, 11.1111111111111, 47.4576271186441, 100), status = c("A", 
    "B", "C", "C", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "C", "C", "C", "A", 
    "B", "C", "B", "C", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"), category = c("CAT3", 
    "CAT1", "CAT3", "CAT2", "CAT1", "CAT1", "CAT1", "CAT3", "CAT2", 
    "CAT3", "CAT2", "CAT1", "CAT1", "CAT1", "CAT2", "CAT2", "CAT1", 
    "CAT1", "CAT1", "CAT1", "CAT3", "CAT3", "CAT3", "CAT1")), .Names = c("date", 
    "cnt1", "cnt2", "per", "status", "category"), row.names = c(NA, 
    -24L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))



 ggplot(data, aes(x=date, y=cnt2)) + 
      scale_y_log10(breaks=c(1,10,100,1000,5000)) +
      scale_size_continuous(trans="sqrt",range = c(1, 5),breaks=c(5,10,25,50,75,100)) +
      geom_point(aes(col=category, size=per, shape=status), alpha=0.7)
```

[image]

Comment: It looks like you can change the shape in the size legend with `override.aes` (add `guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = 17))` to `scale_size_*`), which doesn't answer your question.  What would you want such a legend to look like?  Are you picturing multiple columns?

Comment: @aosmith basically the ideal case would be a circle, a triangle and a square next to each other in each row of the legend. That way it is easier to know the size of all shapes. It is hard to look at the circles and guess what the triangle of the same size would be without having a visual reference

Answer (score 2):

I found a workaround as it seems there is no easy way to do this. The ideal solution would be having the shapes next to each other and mentioning the number once in the legend instead of repeating it. Also, this workaround can be more parametric since with a changing number of `status` and displaying a new shape all of the vectors fed to override function can be constructed correctly:

```
    l=c(5,10,25,50,75,100)
    mybreaks=c(rep(l,3))
    myshapes=c(rep(15,6),rep(16,6),rep(17,6))

    ggplot(data, aes(x=date, y=cnt2)) + 
    scale_y_log10(breaks=c(1,10,100,1000,5000)) +
    scale_size_continuous(trans="sqrt",range = c(1, 5),breaks=mybreaks) +
    geom_point(aes(col=category, size=per, shape=status), alpha=0.7)  +
    guides(size=guide_legend(ncol=3,override.aes = list( shape =myshapes)))
```

[image]